# Accretion disks on neutron star binaries

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astronomy, astrophysics, accretion-disk

Why does hydrogen gas from accretion disks not constantly get sucked onto/into a neutron star or into a black hole? I understand that some gets sucked into the black hole and some may come down and explode on the surface of the neutron star(from my understanding it usually happens on the poles), but why would it not just all get sucked in, and that brings up the question, how/why do they even form?

Comment: In order for matters to fall inwards it must lose enough gravitational energy (by heating up nearer to center disk) and angular momentum (turbulence enhanced viscosity is responsible for redistribution of angular momentum to exterior part of disk)

Comment: This would be a great answer. :)

Comment: Actually I'm unfamiliar with turbulence enhanced viscosity mechanism perhaps someone could lend a hand here, sorry.